# Why do I get an error when importing these PNG files?

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting an error opening my PNG files for a space invaders game I am making through a tutorial. My current code is:

```
# Load Images
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_red_small.png"))
GREEN_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_green_small.png"))
BLUE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_blue_small.png"))

# Player Ship
YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_yellow.png"))

# Lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_red.png"))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_green.png"))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_blue.png"))
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_yellow.png"))

# Background
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background-black.png"))
```

When I run this code I am getting an error stating:

```
    pygame 1.9.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brunoaldridge/Desktop/Space Invader/game.py", line 7, in <module>
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_red_small.png"))
pygame.error: Couldn't open assets/pixel_ship_red_small.png
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I have the python3 build set up on sublime and the PNG files are in the folder with the code file.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths instead (it's always better to do so) :

```
import os

curr_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) # Where your .py file is located
assets_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'assets') # The assets folder path
```

Final code :

```
# Load Images
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_ship_red_small.png"))
GREEN_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_ship_green_small.png"))
BLUE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_ship_blue_small.png"))

# Player Ship
YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_ship_yellow.png"))

# Lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_laser_red.png"))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_laser_green.png"))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_laser_blue.png"))
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "pixel_laser_yellow.png"))

# Background
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join( assets_path, "background-black.png"))
```

Hope, this solves your problem.

Comment: Maybe you could edit this answer to include information about how to change the current working directory with `os.chdir()`.  Obviously the OP's issue is that the PNG file is either not where they are supposed to be, or the program is running in a different directory.